# Inserting russian characters from perl to oracle

Tags: oracle, perl, utf-8, cyrillic

I'm trying to insert (using Perl 5.8) Russian characters into an oracle db that's set to:

```
1 NLS_LANGUAGE RUSSIAN
2 NLS_TERRITORY CIS
3 NLS_CURRENCY р.
4 NLS_ISO_CURRENCY CIS
5 NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS , 
6 NLS_CALENDAR GREGORIAN
7 NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD.MM.RR
8 NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE RUSSIAN
9 NLS_CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
10 NLS_SORT RUSSIAN
11 NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF
12 NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
13 NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
14 NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
15 NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY р.
16 NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
17 NLS_COMP BINARY
18 NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS BYTE
19 NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Before I open the connection to via DBD::Oracle I set my perl env. to

$ENV{NLS_LANG} = 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8'

However for some reason the russian characters are not making correctly to the DB.
Could anyone advise why?

Thanks

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could edit your post to include: 1) a sample of how you're doing the inserts in Perl; 2) Sample input data; 3) What you're seeing in the database that's "wrong"; and 4) How you're looking in the database and determining it's "wrong".  Without all of that, it's going to be awfully hard for anybody to answer the question.

Comment: It may be that they are making it INTO the DB okay, but look wrong when queried from the DB (eg if the querying client doesn't have the right characterset).

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to diagnose whats going on whithout the full stack of products and OS involved both in the insert and the select operations. I had similar issues with the € euro symbol and it took some days to get the full picture. It involved putty encoding, Linux locale, Linux sessions NLS_LANG, Windows CodePage, Windows CMD codePages and character fonts used, and Windows session NLS_LANG. If you are doing web programming, the encoding of pages and httpd could be another factor. Make sure the data is ok in the DB inserting through a stack of products and retreiving through another one. I set it up so I could insert/select same data with any combination of Linux, Windows and Windows CMD, as a probe that it gets right in the DB. If you use just one system you can insert €, retrieve €, and don't realize that the DB is keeping something it does not recognize as an €. This gets unnoticed until....

Also regardind text I/O you should use your OS/web server locale encoding in NLS_LANG and not the DB one. For example in Windows usually a MSWINxxxx. The conversion to AL32UTF8 is done for you by sqlnet.

Comment: one thing often worth doing, esp if you have just one product stack to test with: insert a string such as '€' and select it back, along with its length. If you get a single symbol back but a character length of 3, something's wrong...